# How can I construct a simple case that a message is relayed?

Tags: omnet++

The message is first transmitted by a vehicle1 and relayed by vehicle2.

net.ned is as follows.

```
simple vehicle1
{
    @display("i=device/wifilaptop;p=230,40");
    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;
}

//
// TODO documentation
//
simple vehicle2
{
    @display("i=device/wifilaptop;p=230,40");
    gates:
        input radioIn @directIn;
}

//
// TODO documentation
//
network Network
{
    @display("bgb=225,175");
    types:
    submodules:
        vehicle1: vehicle1 {
            @display("p=44,87");
        }
        vehicle2: vehicle2 {
            @display("p=188,87");
        }
}
```

The vehicle1.cc is as follows.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class vehicle1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  cMessage *msg;
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(vehicle1);

void vehicle1::initialize()
{
    EV << "client initialize" << "\n";

    msg = new cMessage("Emergency");
    send(msg, "out");
}

void vehicle1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
   // msg = new cMessage("Emergency")
   // send(msg, "out"); // send out the message
}
```

and the vehicle2.cc is as follows.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class vehicle2 : public cSimpleModule
{
  cMessage *msg;
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(vehicle2);

void vehicle2::initialize()
{
}

void vehicle2::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    msg = new cMessage("Emergency");
    send(msg, "out"); // send out the message
}
```

But the following error is printed.

> send()/sendDelayed(): No such gate or gate vector: 'out' -- in module (vehicle1) Network.vehicle1 (id=2), during network initialization

How can I construct it?

Answer (score 0):

You simulate a radio network, so you should use `sendDirect()` instead of `send()` because vehicles do not have connections between them. To send a message using `sendDirect()` one has to obtain a pointer to the destination module and the name of gate. Here is an example how to do it:

```
void vehicle1::initialize()
{
    EV << "client initialize" << "\n";

    msg = new cMessage("Emergency");

    cModule *mod= getParentModule()->getSubmodule("vehicle2");
    sendDirect(msg, mod, "radioIn");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I use the sendDirect. But I don't know how can I relay the message. I think "the new cMessage" is the new generated message. And a code in initialize() is not worked. The code in handleMessage only is worked. How can I handle the received message?